# Trying to understand Django's communication between view and template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

(edited)
I come from a web2py background and find Django a much more complicated framework to learn and use than web2py.

After the first answer, I have adapted the description of my problem.

In my view I have:

```
def team(request):
hr = dict(name="Some Name", photo="/static/images/HR.jpg", url="http://some.website.com/?page_id=3602")
js = dict(name="Some Name2", photo="/static/images/JS.jpg", url="http://some.website.com/?page_id=3608")
context = {team:[hr,js]}
return render(request, "wos_2017_2/team.html", context)
```

In the template I have

```
<ul>
   {% for person in context.team %}
   <li> {{ person.name }} {{ person.photo }} {{ person.url }} </li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

There is absolutely no output.

This works in normal python:

```
hr = dict(name="Some Name", photo="/static/images/HR.jpg", url="http://some.website.com/?page_id=3602")
js = dict(name="Some Name2", photo="/static/images/JS.jpg", url="http://some.website.com/?page_id=3608")
context = dict(team = [hr,js])
for i in context['team']:
    print(i['name'], i['photo'], i['url'])
```

With output

```
Some Name /static/images/HR.jpg http://some.website.com/?page_id=3602
Some Name2 /static/images/JS.jpg http://some.website.com/?page_id=3608
```

Why am I not getting any result in Django?

Answer (score 3):

Your first example is correct. Sadly you have a small typo in your first line of code:

```
hr = dict(name="Some Name, ...),
```

The line ends with a comma `,`. Now `hr` is becomes a `tuple` with a single element: the dict. Without the comma this works:

```
{{ team.0.name }}
{{ team.1.name }}
```

With your updated answer you need to change `context.team` to `team` in your template:

```
{% for person in team %}
```

The context dictionary is 'unpacked' in the template.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo.  Correcting it and using your suggested `{{ team.0.name }}` changed nothing in the output.  :(

Comment: Are you sure you are using this version: `{team:[hr,js]}`? I copied your code and it was working correctly.

Comment: This is my present code: `def team(request):
    hr = dict(name="Some Name", photo="/static/images/HR.jpg", url="http://some.website.com/?page_id=3602")
    js = dict(name="Some Name2", photo="/static/images/JS.jpg", url="http://some.website.com/?page_id=3608")
    return render(request, "wos_2017_2/team.html", {team: [hr, js]})`  and in the template `   <h3>The data-management team</h3>

                <ul>
                    <li>{{ team.0.name }}</li>
                    <li>{{ team.1.name }}</li>
                </ul>` (How do I post code in a comment?)

Comment: @JohannSpies don't add the code in the comments, it is illegible. Post it in an edit of your question.

Comment: Apologies.  I will rephrase my question above.

Comment: using ` {% for person in team %}` in the template was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to comment so I had to post an answer.

Only immutable data types can be used as keys, i.e. no lists or dictionaries can be used If you use a mutable data type as a key, you get an error message.Tuple as keys are okay.

With what i can tell is the problem is in your view code:

This

```
context = {team:[hr,js]}
```

should be this:

```
context = {"team":[hr,js]}
```

or

```
context = dict(team=[hr,js])
```

Comment: Thanks.  Correcting this did not make any difference in the zero html output however.

Comment: i think your iteration code in template has a problem. try changing `{% for person in context.team %}` to  `{% for key, person in context.items %}`

Comment: That also does not make a difference.  It is a bit frustrating.  In Web2py if you try and use a variable in  the template (web2py-view) that did not come from the controler (django view) it will through an error.  But in this case there is no error and I struggle to find out what is going on.

Comment: I don't see any problem but you can try debugging the code put some breakpoints in the view and see if the data you are sending to template is going through or not. Also check your console on browser and inspect the `ul` tag you are trying to show. Try to find the exact line of code which is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
                    {% for person in team %}
                    <li> {{ person.name }} {{ person.photo }} {{ person.url }} </li>
                    {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

Was the correct way to read the dictionary in the template.